# Bootstrap popup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide the popup when clicked any where else but not on the popup and the button

it works fine for first case but after that when it hides it requires two click to show . how can i do it with one click only.

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {

  if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' &&
    $(e.target).parents('.feedsPopup').length == 0 &&
    $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0)
    $('.feedsPopup').popover('hide');
});

$(document).on('show.bs.popover', '.feedsPopup', function() {

  var popup = $(this);

  $(popup).attr('data-content', 'coooooooool');

});




$('#myid').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button>')

$('.feedsPopup').popover();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="border:1px solid red;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="myid"></div>

</body>
```

And also i am trying to hide all other popup and show only one i am doing `$('.feedsPopup').popup('hide');` and then `$(this).popup('show');` on `click method of feedsPopup` but if i do that it will hide current popup also so no popover is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it simple and trigger the button click like this:

```js
var popup = [{
  id: 'button1',
  open: false
}, {
  id: 'button2',
  open: false
}];

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' && !$(e.target).hasClass('popover-content')) {
    for (var i in popup) {
      if (popup[i].open) {
        popup[i].open = false;
        $("#" + popup[i].id).trigger('click')
      }
    }
  }
});

$(document).on('show.bs.popover', '.feedsPopup', function() {
  for (var i in popup) {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == popup[i].id) {
      popup[i].open = true;
      console.log(popup[i].open)
    }
  }
  $(this).attr('data-content', 'coooooooool');
});

$('#myid').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button>')

$('button').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', popup[i].id)
})

$('.feedsPopup').popover();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="border:1px solid red;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="myid"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: It's triggering when I click on the body too. :)

Comment: Yes, it is like you want. You will hide the popover if you click anywhere except the button or popover.

Comment: Then put a ID on the button and trigger the click by `$("#your id").trigger('click')`

Comment: ok if i have 10 button how will i find out which button is clicked and whose id should i choose if you look at my example you will see that button is generated dynamically

Comment: or what i can do is to save the $(this) value in a global variable as i am using class not id then use that variable in body click event

Comment: @Zorken17 what do you say about it

Comment: YOUR SOLUTION IS WRONG IT ALSO TRIGGERS WHEN YOU CLICK ON BODY

Comment: MY SOLUTION WORKS WITH YOUR PROBLEM DESCRIPTION ABOVE!

Comment: NO it shows popup also when you click on body but popup should only be visible when you click on button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134085/discussion-between-zorken17-and-codenut).

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy solution for this:

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="myid"></div>

</body>
<script>
    $('body').on('click', function (e)
    {

        if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' &&
          $(e.target).parents('.feedsPopup').length == 0 &&
          $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0)
        {
            $('.feedsPopup').popover('hide');
            $('.feedsPopup').removeAttr('pshow');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('show.bs.popover', '.feedsPopup', function ()
    {

        var popup = $(this);
        popup.attr('pshow', 'pshow');
        $(popup).attr('data-content', 'coooooooool');

    });

    $('#myid').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary feedsPopup"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Popover on top</button>')

    $('.feedsPopup').popover();

    $('.feedsPopup').one('click', function ()
    {
        $(this).on('click', function ()
        {
            if ($(this).attr('pshow') != 'pshow')
            {
                $(this).click();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you code looks really interesting to me would you please explain it a little

Comment: i am looking at page element and i can't see any attribute pshow in button why?

Comment: I added another click to the button when you click on that. But this adds only after first click. $('.feedsPopup').one('click', function ()... adds event to each button after it clicked one time.

Comment: I edited my answer and this is complete. Feel free to say if you need explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the definition of your button `data-trigger="focus"` and it should work without

```
   $('body').on('click', function(e) {    
     if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover' &&
       $(e.target).parents('.feedsPopup').length == 0 &&
       $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0)
       $('.feedsPopup').popover('hide');
   });
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9dux9kh/)

**Edit:** [reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Comment: it will hide when you click on `coool` which i don't what

Comment: i want it to hide when it is clicked on elements other than `popover` and `feedsPopup`